# Xcode 7.3 variable name autocomplete

Tags: swift, xcode, autocomplete

Is there any way to have autocomplete for variable name with similar name with the class name?

For example if I have this custom class

```
class AVeryLongClassName {
    var varName: Int
}
```

And I'm planning to make a variable:

```
var aVeryLongClassName: AVeryLongClassName
```

Is there any way to make Xcode suggest variable name that is similar with class name  (aVeryLongClassName is similar with AveryLongClassName) in autocomplete?

It already does the autocomplete for the AveryLongClassName class, however, it doesn't autocomplete the aVeryLongClassName variable name

[image]

[image]

Comment: It already does the autocomplete for the AveryLongClassName class, however, it doesn't autocomplete the aVeryLongClassName variable name

Comment: It does, you just usually have to hit the down arrow one or more times to get to it

Comment: I edited the question to show what I meant